# Where does "Attacke!" come from?

Tags: etymology, loanword, imperative

I have been learning German on Duolingo for most of this year. I've also been watching some TV shows in German - [Arthur und die Freunde der Tafelrunde](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_und_die_Freunde_der_Tafelrunde) and [Dark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_(TV_series)). Both of these shows have featured a character exclaiming "Attacke!" and then... well in one show, the character attacked something, and in the other, he jumped into a lake, haha. I gleefully assumed it was the imperative form of the German word that our English word (and battle cry) came from. But then I actually looked it up in [linguee.de](http://linguee.de) and the only entry is for a noun. Is this what they are saying? Are they just copying something English-speaking TV says?  Or perhaps it's actually in first-person and they are declaring that they themselves are attacking?

How is this one-word phrase understood to a German speaker?

Comment: It surprises me again and again that English speakers assume that English was the origin for all other languages. As for the German words *Attacke* and *attackieren*, they are of French origin and have existed for several centuries already. And I am quite certain that also the English noun *attack* and the verb *to attack* originate from French.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Isn't he actually saying that the English word came from the German one? You're probably right that both originated from French, though...

Comment: @Lykanion: in my understanding, the question "Are they just copying something English-speaking TV says?" describes, that the Germans are copying something from people in an english speaking TV would say.

Comment: "(....) he jumped into a lake". Yes, "Attacke" is the order to attack somebody. But this word is also often used for "let's go" or "here we go". So before jumping into a lake you could say "Attacke!" or for example you've had a meeting at work and decided to solve a problem in a specific way. Here you could also say "Attacke" for "let's do this!"

Comment: You missed the verb "attackieren".

Comment: @ShegitBrahm That's a question, though, not an assumption, and not an unreasonable one, at that. I was referring to _"the German word that our English word [...] came from."_ But maybe I'm misinterpreting either Nacht or Björn Friedrich.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich My *first* assumption was that the English word came from German. My *last* guess was the other way around, since English is learned all throughout Europe nowadays, and everyone watches American television.

Comment: @CarstenS I did indeed! I am still learning to use these dictionary websites I suppose. Thank you!

Comment: @Björn_Friedrich Yes, the English word "attack" entered the corpus around 1600 and derives from the Old French word *attaque*, itself deriving from the Italian *attacco*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word ["die Attacke"](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Attacke_Angriff_Schmerzanfall) is a German noun - indeed, it entered German as a loanword (from French), but it is by no means a recent addition.

Using a noun rather than an imperative is not unusual in German, especially when the intention is a brief (one-word) utterance rather than a sentence. Instead of "Attacke!", one could usually just as well yell "Angriff!", to mention a more or less synonymous noun. Other common examples include "Zugriff!" (the order given to a police squad to detain someone ... at least the way it's presented on TV) or "Schnitt!" ("Cut!" during film production).

Note that "attacke" is not a verb form at all; the verb for "Attacke" is "attackieren", so the imperative and the first person singular indicative would both be "attackiere" - though it is rather unusual to use that word intransitively.

Comment: It would be useful to mention that "Attacke" has its origin in the military, as a command to, well, attack.

Comment: @tofro And without checking, I therefore  suppose that it has French origin

Comment: Thank you, "Using a noun rather than an imperative is not unusual in German" is exactly the explanation I was looking for.

Comment: More examples: "Ruhe!", "Schluss!", "Hilfe!"